# How to force Scrapy to show all items instead of just the last one?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Having the following spider:

```
import scrapy

class ScrapeNames(scrapy.Spider):
    name='final2'

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.trekearth.com/members/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        for entry in response.xpath('//table[@class="member-table"]'):

            for name in entry.xpath('.//tr[@class="row"]/td/p/a/text()|.//tr/td/p/a/text()').extract():
                item['name'] = name
            for photo in entry.xpath('.//tr[@class="row"]/td[6]/a/text()|.//tr[@class="row"]/td[6]/text()|.//tr/td[6]/text()|.//tr/td[6]/a/text()').extract():
                item['photo'] = photo
        yield item
```

I want to extract number of photos taken by the user and then export it to csv. However in my `.csv` I only have the last item in the table on this page (see screenshot bellow).

[image]

What I want is obviously to have a member name and number of photos taken for all of the users on a page. What am I doing wrong? How to fix this?

**EDIT:**
Possibly this is essential as well but my `items.py` file looks like this:

```
import scrapy


class FinalItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    photo = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

**FOLLOW UP QUESTION:**

I have introduced some improvements into my code which is now:

```
class ScrapeMovies(scrapy.Spider):
    name='final2'

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.trekearth.com/members/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = FinalItem()
        for entry in response.xpath('//table[@class="member-table"]'):
            for name in entry.xpath('.//tr[@class="row"]/td/p/a/text()|.//tr/td/p/a/text()').extract():
                names = entry.xpath('.//tr[@class="row"]/td/p/a/text()|.//tr/td/p/a/text()').extract()
                item['name'] = ";".join(names)
            for photos in entry.xpath('.//tr[@class="row"]/td[6]/a/text()|.//tr[@class="row"]/td[6]/text()|.//tr/td[6]/text()|.//tr/td[6]/a/text()').extract():
                photos = entry.xpath('.//tr[@class="row"]/td[6]/a/text()|.//tr[@class="row"]/td[6]/text()|.//tr/td[6]/text()|.//tr/td[6]/a/text()').extract()
                item['photo'] = ";".join(photos)
        yield item
```

However this created a mess in final `.csv` which now looks like this:

[image]

Is there a simple way to fix this?

Sample desired output in .csv bellow:

[image]

**EDIT2:**

My spider now:

```
import scrapy
from final.items import FinalItem



class ScrapeMovies(scrapy.Spider):
    name='final2'

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.trekearth.com/members/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//table[@class="member-table"]//tr[position() > 1]'):
            item = FinalItem()
            item['name'] = row.xpath('./td[2]//a/text()').extract_first()
            item['photos'] = row.xpath('string(./td[6])').extract_first()
            yield item
```

Still does not yield proper result. I have empty .csv only. Updated settings.py

Comment: Ummm, you might have changed the delimiter (in windows settings)by accident. We'll wait for the responses then I'll offer mine if they don't work.

Comment: @ElvirMuslic what is your idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You need to have this line in your `settings.py` (site blocks default Scrapy user-agent):

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.170 Safari/537.36'
```

and next this will work:

```
def parse(self, response):

    for row in response.xpath('//table[@class="member-table"]//tr[position() > 1]'):
        item = FinalItem()
        item['name'] = row.xpath('./td[2]//a/text()').extract_first()
        item['photos'] = row.xpath('string(./td[6])').extract_first()
        yield item
```

Comment: great answer! However i have one more question (added to question body).

Comment: To make myself clear. I want "username, number of photos taken" in .csv two columns simply. I want to have it identical to my first output however for all users in a table. Hope it is cleare for you @gangabass. See screenshot in my update

Comment: @Mrowkacala What output do you have?

Comment: Empty .csv file

Comment: @Mrowkacala my code works for me. What User-Agent  are you using in settings.py ?

Comment: When i start the spider i use: ' USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36" ' but not in settings.py but in command prompt